# Word for something (e.g. a group of friends) being male-dominated?

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking for a word that can sum up something that is largely defined by and composed of - but not restricted to - men.

For example: "My first month at university has been ________; I haven't made any female friends."

Another idea that comes to mind is the movie industry, but that's male-favoring, which I'm not exactly looking for. I'm looking for something that doesn't favor males, but just happens to have drawn in a lot of them, or rather, not drawn in any females.

Comment: How about "monk-like"?

Comment: There needs to be a new word for this. Maniserable.

Comment: boxing gym, weight room, submarine, gay bar, trouser snake pit, stonewall

Comment: Edited title to, IMHO, better reflect what you're asking...

Comment: I know it's not one word, but why not `sausage fest`?

Comment: @dandavis I wouldn't take most of those to mean what OP is looking for, but +1 anyway for the phrase "trouser snake pit"

Comment: @Tijmen Exactly what immediately came to my mind too XD

Comment: "stag" ? stag-ey/stag-esque/stag-like

Answer (score 57):

"male-dominated", as in your title, is the term I'd use. Otherwise, if you're open to a slang term, you could use:

[sausage-fest](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/sausage_fest)
A party or gathering where all, or the vast majority of, the participants are male.

Comment: It has been a “sausage party”, also works.

Comment: Sausage party/fest can have a slightly homophobic/sexist feel to it if you don't have a sarcastic tone. I've most often heard it by (single)guys going to a party/gathering and expect there to be girls there to hit on. At least I feel a bit uncomfortable hearing it.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren: I'm struggling to find a homophobic undertone in your example, regardless of intonation. "Sausage fest" does not in any way imply anything about the sexual preference of the attendees (not even necessarily that of the speaker, e.g. I could call our office party a sausage fest without necessarily implying that I'm trying to pick up women there).

Comment: @ViktorMellgren: The only way I can see somewhat of a homophobic undertone is if you say something like "oh, I know _Mike_ would just love to spend all night at a sausage fest". And even then it remains arguable, since the statement is only _calling Mike gay_, it's not necessarily saying anything bad about being gay.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren I'm gay and also don't see the homophobia here (which doesn't mean you're wrong).  Sexist, sure.  Can you elaborate?

Comment: @Flater Agreed... if you know of any sausage-parties in the area, give them my number.  Please and thank you.

Comment: Regardless of any potentially sexist/homophobic connotations, sausage fest/party is a crude idiom, and may not be appropriate for all audiences.

Comment: @thumbtackthief, Flater: Homophobic was maybe not the correct term to use, but what I was after was the situation where you for example arrange a board game night or whatever and your (male)friend arrives and sees only guys, he calls sausage fest, and somewhat implying that there are "homo-cooties" in the air. (Maybe this is a cultural nuance for the equivalent Swedish word *korvfest*). This being said, it could be considered non appropriate at times whereas male-dominated is the safe bet and also universally understood.

Comment: @ViktorMellgren Gotcha.  That makes sense.

Answer (score 17):

In the UK (and possibly Australia) you might say: My first term at university has been a bit [blokey](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blokey).

Comment: I never heard of "blokey", and in your example sentence I wouldn't understand it to mean "mostly consisting of blokes".

Comment: @MrLister: It's definitely a [valid word](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/blokey) and would be understood in the UK. The trouble is, it typically means "doing stereotypically male activities", so I'd understand that the speaker had spent the first term mostly playing football (say) rather than shopping for clothes - not necessarily that they were with only men and not women...

Answer (score 9):

How about: My first term at university was estrogen-poor.
Or - My first term at university was testosterone-heavy, or testosterone-dominated.

Comment: I haven't heard this term used before, and would guess the wrong meaning for it.  (I'd assume that the speaker was referring to biochemistry rather than the sex of their friends, so would interpret it as "I made lots of rash decisions/played lots of contact sports/etc."  Or possibly even "I had a medical condition due to a hormonal imbalance, and so missed a lot of lectures.")

Comment: I have heard those terms many times, and they've always been understood. But there is usually more context than just the word itself.

Comment: Reading biology then?

Comment: @WeatherVane ... "reading biology"?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai: The American / international(?) English translation of "reading biology" would be "studying biology".

Comment: @PeterCordes Ah, gotcha. Thank you. It was quite the confounding fragment

Comment: @Azor-Ahai lmfao that's the weirdest exchange I've ever seen xD What are you even doing

Comment: @theonlygusti What?

Comment: @Azor-Ahai to not know what "reading biology" means and then describe it as a "confounding fragment" sounds pretentious af, both "confounding" and "fragment" are such rarely-used words that your sentence is ridiculously hilarious

Comment: @theonlygusti Well it's pretty ridiculously hilarious to write out "xD" in 2017

Comment: I'd understand references to testosterone to have overtones of "macho", as in "testosterone poisoning" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Testosterone_poisoning

Answer (score 6):

If you are looking for a quip, you could go with "man-tastic".  Also, it might help inspire better answers if we could know the gender of the speaker and how he/she feels about the situation stated.

Comment: Note that this sounds pretty positive, if used in the example sentence given it might imply that the speaker was glad for all the opportunities for flings with different men. Doesn't really sound like the thing they were originally going for, although it might have been.

Answer (score 6):

It is not terribly colloquial, but perhaps the most correct single word is

[Androcentric](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/androcentric)

> centered on, emphasizing, or dominated by males or masculine interests

Comment: beautiful word, but I think it is the exact meaning OP stated they were trying to avoid. Androcentric implies an 'active' focus on men, rather than 'happens to involve / draw men into it'. I would have said "Androphilic" along those lines, but I doubt it exists as a known word.

Answer (score 1):

My answer cops to the situation, being the first month at uni.

> My first month at university has been girl shy.

Or more generally

> My friends are all girl shy.

Comment: As a US English speaker, I would take this to mean "shy around women", especially in your second example sentence.

Comment: @thumbtackthief well yes, I agree. I posted this because in the first month, the fresher had not made any female friends. It's an angle.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to add a bit of a sciencey spin you could do:

> My first month at university has been heterogametic.

From the [Biology Online Dictionary](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Heterogametic_sex):

> The sex of a species possessing dissimilar sex chromosomes
>
> Supplement
>
> In humans, the heterogametic sex is the male. The gametes produced may contain either X-chromosome or Y-chromosome.

Comment: This is a bit confusing on first blush because the group is homogenous, even though "heterogametic" is correct.

Comment: I'm always amazed when people suggest extraordinarily obscure words that readers/listeners are almost certain to *not* understand, and yet you see them all over this site.

Comment: @jpmc26 But if you hear a word you know you don't know, you can always ask what it means, or look it up. Some of the other answers to this question, while consisting of more common words, can be confusing because they are not as unambiguous.

Comment: @jpmc26 Every word is extraordinarily obscure before you have read/heard it the first time.

Comment: @jpmc26: guess what?  People who like to play with language hang out and post answers on english.SE.  Sometimes that means inventing a possible use for an obscure word.  I think most people realize that it's more of a "this is an interesting idea that probably wouldn't really work" thing.

Comment: @PeterCordes StackExchange doesn't really welcome speculative, not very useful answers, though.

Comment: @jpmc26: That's why they usually don't get many upvotes.  I was just guessing at the motivation of the people who posted them, i.e. why they maybe thought it was a good idea at the time.  I basically agree with your sentiment that there's significant clutter.  Usually they're not so bad they need a downvote, though, and like this case, it was an interesting idea.

Comment: @jpmc26 The OP didn't specify a term that would be understood by the lowest common denominator; this is a site "for linguists, etymologists, and serious English language enthusiasts" so it shouldn't be surprising that terms that are likely only known and used by such people would sometimes pop up. OPs who prefer a slang term or a term that would be widely recognized are welcome to include such requirements in their questions; absent such a restriction, I would assume that an obscure but on-point answer is acceptable.